# /home/hadoop/bin/hadoop missing in ami 4.x

Tags: amazon-emr, amazon-ami

I am trying to migrate a legacy mapreduce pipeline that is using ami 3.x to ami 4.x. It currently has bash scripts as part of the bootstrapping and one of them calls `hadoop fs-get s3n://somefile ~/otherfile`. This fails in my current migration attempt to ami 4.x. And adding `ls /home/hadoop/bin` the script shows that the directory `/home/hadoop/bin` does not exist so of course the binary `/home/hadoop/bin/hadoop` would not exist. Is there something I need to configure to ensure the `hadoop` binary exists? I can't seem to find anything obvious in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file system layout changed considerably between 3.x and 4.x. The differences between 3.x and 4.x and instructions for migrating can be found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-4.1.0/emr-release-differences.html

The short answer for solving your issue though is that you should use "aws s3 cp" instead of "hadoop fs-get" in bootstrap actions, since Hadoop is not installed until after bootstrap actions run on 4.x+.